# Variable interpolation inside Map directive

Tags: nginx

I am trying to map a variable inside the http directive in Nginx.

When left alone, the variable alone gets expanded, if I add anything else to the string the expansion stops working.

```
http {

    map $host $foo {
        #default "$host";                    # - this works fine and returns 'localhost' 
        default "This is my host: $host";    # - THIS DOESN'T WORK
    }

    server {

        location / {
            echo $foo;
        }

    }

}
```

Do you have any suggestions to make the expansion work inside the map?

Comment: Raised a ticket at Ningx http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/663#ticket

Comment: Looks like the ticket was accepted and completed May 2016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the `map` directive [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) :

> The resulting value can be a string or another variable (0.9.0).

**Update:** This functionality has been added to version 1.11.2 of NGinx, as per Comment #7 here: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/663#comment:7

Comment: The question is how do I return a string with the expanded variable on it.

Comment: The one related to the question. Are you saying it can't be done?

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this without a map? I am basically using the map to give-me different strings depending on the http referer.

Comment: @user745079 Use a third party scripting language like [lua](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule) or [perl](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html) (careful with that latter one, it's very experimental) and write handlers.