# Interpolating Multiple Variables Inside of Nginx Map Directive

Tags: nginx

This is an updated version of this question. (I've never asked a question on here so I can't comment on the original)

[Variable interpolation inside Map directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976535/variable-interpolation-inside-map-directive)

According to the docs combinations of strings and variables are now allowed. As seen here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map

and here: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/663

> The resulting value can contain text, variable (0.9.0), and their combination (1.11.0).

However I still can't get it work.

We have a large number of redirects and as per the following suggestion I'm trying to implement them using the map directive. https://serverfault.com/questions/450325/nginx-and-try-files-try-named-location-with-rewrites-before-fallback

Here is an example mapping:

```
map $uri $redirect {
    /wrong/path /right/path/;
    ~^/another/wrong/path/(?<path>.*)$ /another/right/path/$path;
}
```

This returns the literal string `/another/right/path/$path`

This works fine:

```
map $uri $redirect {
    /wrong/path /right/path/;
     ~^/another/wrong/path/(?<path>.*)$ $path
}
```

So I know that the variable isn't the problem.

Does anyone know how to do combine strings with variables in the map directive? What am I missing here?

I am on version 1.11.2

Answer (score -1):

You can combine strings as example below.

```
map $host $_env_right_url {
  default right-path.com;
}

map $uri $redirect_uri {
    ~^/wrong/path/?$ https://$_env_right_url/rightPath;
    ~^/second/wrong/path/?$ https://$_env_right_url/second/rightPath;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name WRONG-path.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @redirect-map;
    }

    location @redirect-map {
        if ($redirect_uri) {  # redirect if the variable is defined
            return 301 $redirect_uri;
        }
    }
}
```